# Scrollbar shows without apparent reason in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

`Blue inline-block #b` with `vertical-align: middle` is placed inside `red #a`. At some moment `blue #b` have full height of its parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/TK2qs/1/

Troublemaker is Opera only [1], which is putting vertical scrollbar on window even when there is some space below `red parent #a` [2]. The super funny detail is that there is really nothing in markup that seems to occupy extra space below `red #a`—even `document element` does not take up this space.

Noted behaviour vanishes when `display: inline-block` or `vertical-align: middle` rule of `blue #b` is discarded. Still, it will be useful to find a solution which keeps both of these rules on.

*To reproduce problem in JSFiddle, please drag borders of bottom-right subframe.*

Thank you for your attention!

[1_] Checked only in my current version: 12.11.

[2_] Some 40-50 pixels in [jsfiddle.net example][1]. Size varies with `red #a` height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Mpmgv/

I have found two workarounds myself.

First is to hide overflow of `blue #b`. The fact that it is a viable solution gives me the thought that *invisible big element* is probably situated somewhere inside `blue #b`, and not anywhere else.

Second workaround is to make synthetic absolute-positioned child inside `blue #b`. And so all content intended to be placed in `blue #b` will go into synthetic child.

You can check both of these solutions out by adding appropriate class on `red #a` element.

Still, I wait for and highly appreciate any thoughts about reasons why such a bizarre problem occurs in Opera.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with furikuretsu's answer.  `overflow:hidden` gets rid of the mysterious invisible content.

Weirdly, the more text I put inside `div#c`, the smaller the space became.  When the text fills over half the height, the space disappears completely.  This is an observation, not a solution!

I reported this as a bug to Opera. No idea if it'll do any good mind...

Comment: Really nice observation about relation of #c's inner content size and space below #a, thanks!